# Unable to display the coreect date in raddatepicker using Javascript

Tags: c#, calendar, telerik, rad-controls, telerik-radinput

I am getting a date value from server side and passing it to **javascript** method and then I am assigning the date to Telerik `RadDatePicker` control using **Javascript**.

I am getting date as

```
var Date1="25/01/2013 00:00:00";
function SetDate(Date1)
{
     var datepicker = $find("<%= RadDatePicker1.ClientID %>"); 
     var cusDate=new date(Date1); 
     datepicker.SetDate(cusDate);
}
```

Here I am getting date as **1/4/2014** instead of **25/1/2013**. I am Unable to display the date in `raddatepicker`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 var datepicker = $find("<%= RadDatePicker1.ClientID %>"); 
    datepicker.set_selectedDate(cusDate);
```